# double angle condition

Tags: geometry

Let $ABCD$ be a cyclic quadrilateral. Points $E$ and $F$ lie on sides $AB$ and $BC$, respectively, such that $\angle BFE=2\angle
BDE$. Prove that $(EF-FC)AD=AE \cdot CD$.

My attempts are this:

- "constructing" the point $F$ assuming that $E$ is already set. This is my construction: Let $X$ be the point where the circumcircle of $BED$ meets $BC$. Then let $F$ be the intersection of the perpenciular bisector of $EX$ and the line $BC$. (it is easy to check that that point is the point $F$ that satisfies the angle condition)
- Another option is using trig (doubleangle formula) but I can't seem to see the connection yet.

Answer (score 3):

Your construction is actually very useful. I define $X$ to be the point where the circumcircle of $\triangle BED$ meets $BC$ for the second time.

[image]

Then we find $\angle EXB = \angle EDB = \frac12 \angle EFB$, which implies that $\triangle EFX$ is isosceles: $|EF|=|FX|$. This means that $|EF|-|FC|=|FX|-|FC|=|CX|$.

The desired equaility now follows from the similarity $\triangle DAE \sim \triangle DCX$ that can be proven by proving the equality of the angles indicated in the picture.